# Decompress all Gzip files in a Hadoop hdfs directory

Tags: hadoop, gzip, compression

On my HDFS, I have a bunch of gzip files that I want to decompress to a normal format. Is there an API for doing this? Or how could I write a function to do this?

I don't want to use any command-line tools; instead, I want to accomplish this task by writing Java code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a [`CompressionCodec`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/compress/CompressionCodec.html) to decompress the file. The implementation for gzip is [`GzipCodec`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/compress/GzipCodec.html). You get a [`CompressedInputStream`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.3.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/compress/GzipCodec.html) via the codec and out the result with simple IO. Something like this: say you have a file `file.gz`

```
//path of file
String uri = "/uri/to/file.gz";
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(URI.create(uri), conf);
Path inputPath = new Path(uri);

CompressionCodecFactory factory = new CompressionCodecFactory(conf);
// the correct codec will be discovered by the extension of the file
CompressionCodec codec = factory.getCodec(inputPath);

if (codec == null) {
    System.err.println("No codec found for " + uri);
    System.exit(1);
}

// remove the .gz extension
String outputUri =
    CompressionCodecFactory.removeSuffix(uri, codec.getDefaultExtension());

InputStream is = codec.createInputStream(fs.open(inputPath));
OutputStream out = fs.create(new Path(outputUri));
IOUtils.copyBytes(is, out, conf);

// close streams
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you need to get all the files in a directory, the you should get the `FileStatus`es like

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
FileStatus[] statuses = fs.listStatus(new Path("hdfs/path/to/dir"));
```

Then just loop

```
for (FileStatus status: statuses) {
    CompressionCodec codec = factory.getCodec(status.getPath());
    ...
    InputStream is = codec.createInputStream(fs.open(status.getPath());
    ...
}
```

Comment: So actually all of my gziped files are stored in a directory on hdfs and there a bunch of files inside one directory. I want to go through each file inside the directory decompress it and then store the resulted file in a new directory. To get the list of files inside the directory I'm using the code List<File? listFiles = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(temporaryDirectory,null,true);

So how will the above code change to match this. Sorry but I'm really confused about all this, thats why I'm asking. Thanks for the help.

Comment: So my OutputStream will still be the same as:
OutputStream out = fs.create(new Path("hdfs/ouput"));
Correct? So this will keep on copying my InputStream files to the OuputStream path? or am I wrong?

Comment: With my code example I am basically storing the file in the same directory, just decompressed, and without the .gz extension. That's the purpose of the `removeSuffix`. But if you want it stored somewhere else, just change the path and remove the extension yourself. The second part of your question, yes, in the loop you will just be taking the input stream and copying it to the output stream

Comment: Just try it and see what results you get. Let me know if what what doesn't work if it doesn't

Comment: Oh ok, one last question. So are you deleting the .gz extension files also? or are they still there in the input path?

Comment: No, not deleting the, just the extension of the path (so when you save, the .gz extension is not there and the file name is the same). The actual files will still be there. If you want to delete them, you can. But I would practice making this work first before you go deleting anything (if that's what you want). But again, like I said, try it out, play with it, and let me know if you have questions _after_ actually trying it out

Comment: getting error "No codec found for {Path}" any suggestion. i checked path of file is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I use an identity map Hadoop job I wrote in Scalding to change compression / change split size / etc.

```
class IdentityMap(args: Args) extends ConfiguredJob(args) {
  CombineFileMultipleTextLine(args.list("in"): _*).read.mapTo[String, String]('line -> 'line)(identity)
  .write(if (args.boolean("compress")) TsvCompressed(args("out")) else TextLine(args("out")))
}
```

General configuration abstract class:

```
abstract class ConfiguredJob(args: Args) extends Job(args) {
  override def config(implicit mode: Mode): Map[AnyRef, AnyRef] = {
    val Megabyte = 1024 * 1024
    val conf = super.config(mode)
    val splitSizeMax = args.getOrElse("splitSizeMax", "1024").toInt * Megabyte
    val splitSizeMin = args.getOrElse("splitSizeMin", "512").toInt * Megabyte
    val jobPriority = args.getOrElse("jobPriority","NORMAL")
    val maxHeap = args.getOrElse("maxHeap","512m")
    conf ++ Map("mapred.child.java.opts" -> ("-Xmx" + maxHeap),
      "mapred.output.compress" -> (if (args.boolean("compress")) "true" else "false"),
      "mapred.min.split.size" -> splitSizeMin.toString,
      "mapred.max.split.size" -> splitSizeMax.toString,
//      "mapred.output.compression.codec" -> args.getOrElse("codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec"), //Does not work, has to be -D flag
      "mapred.job.priority" -> jobPriority)
  }
}
```