# extract .zip file in hdfs

Tags: unix, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

I want to unzip a .zip file present in hdfs and store the output in hdfs. I tried below command `hadoop fs -text testData/sample/slarge.zip | hadoop fs -put - testData/sample1/uncompressed-file.txt`, but it is not working properly and getting garbage result in output result. Is there any way to do unzip file in hdfs?

Note: the file is a .zip file not .gzip file.

Comment: Similar with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573279/how-to-unzip-gz-files-in-a-new-directory-in-hadoop

Comment: do you see the correct output if you only use the fist part of the command (the `-text` part, without the pipe)? in other words, are the paths you specify correct (I usually prefer absolute paths, starting with `/`).

Comment: I think `hdfs dfs -text` only works with `CompressionCodec` like `gzip` `bzip2` etc.

Comment: @philantrovert the documentation says that "The allowed formats are zip and TextRecordInputStream."

Comment: Also, consider using the new hdfs commands, instead of the old fs (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html), e.g., `hdfs dfs -text ...`

Comment: @vefthym but a zip can be created using different codecs and I'm sure `-text` won't be able to parse them all. Check [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.action/0.2.0/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FsShell.java#FsShell.forMagic%28org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path%2Corg.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem%29)

Comment: @philantrovert I guess you are right. Good one.