# tgz/zip folder containing multiple files unpack in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, unzip

So I have a folder that I zipped and shipped to hdfs, I need to unzip this folder inside hdfs while keeping all the files as they are in the folder.

I am able to run

```
hdfs dfs -cat /user/USERNAME/MYFOLDER/zipped_folder.tgz | zcat | hdfs dfs -put - /user/USERNAME/MYFOLDER/
```

This does the job of unzipping the data, but it puts all of the data into 1 '-' file. I need the unzipped files to be kept as they are, not concatenated into 1 file.

Is there a way in hdfs to do this? I made a copy of the folder as .zip and .tgz if that makes any difference.

Cheers

P.S: I do not have access to local dir, the folder is in hdfs already.

Comment: `zcat` makes a single continuous file stream, which you then are putting into a single output HDFS location. You need a step that extracts and uploads each file separately, which can't really be done with Unix pipes

Comment: ok that makes sense, thank you for the comment, maybe I can write a bash script for this!

Comment: This SO answer has several possible solutions, one using bash and another using Hive. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573279/how-to-unzip-gz-files-in-a-new-directory-in-hadoop