# Hadoop unzip files in directory and move each of them individually to another folder

Tags: hadoop, command-line, hive, hdfs

I am trying to unzip hundreds of files in HDFS and move each of them individually to another folder so that it can be loaded into an external table in Hive. I tried the following command, but it only gave 1 joined file with no name in the target directory.

```
!hdfs dfs -cat /user/[somedir1]/* | hadoop fs -put - /user/[somedir2]/uncompressed/
```

[image]

I need (for instance) 100 compressed files to be decompressed and move each of these decompressed files to the target dir individually for debugging purposes. I can't use another programming language as it will make the project more complicated than it needs to be. I think this can be done using hdfs command line, I just don't know the right one-line syntax.

Comment: You're going to need to loop over every file in the dir.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unzip .gz files in a new directory in hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573279/how-to-unzip-gz-files-in-a-new-directory-in-hadoop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the one line solution of how to uncompress each individual file completely in Shell.

```
for FILE in somedir1/*; do if [[ $FILE == *\.gzip ]] ; then newname='somedir2/'$(basename -s .gzip $FILE); zcat "${FILE}" > $newname; fi; done
```